# Issues w/ .htaccess and wordpress subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Independent WordPress install in a sub-directory and 301 forwarded the domain to the sub directory.  The domain forward works; however, other paths such as "/wp-admin" do not.
I've been unable to find any direction on this.  Can you please point me in the right direction or provide an article explaining how this works?

Example of what was added to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?YourDomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory [L]
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Pointing_your_home_site.27s_URL_to_a_subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?Example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, I've been struggling with this for a few days now.  I swear i'm not incompetent; however, after adding this to the .htaccess in root I had no change.  Also tried it in the sub-directory install since I wasent 100% sure what .htaccess to edit.  Still the same result when trying to access domainb.com/wp-access.  Could it be my web hosting?